# Cannot fetch strapi data when using next.js getStaticProps

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, strapi, getstaticprops

I'm trying to display content from strapi on a next.js app which is statically generated.

I run both strapi & next.js on localhost (strapi on `localhost:1337`, next.js on `localhost:4200`) and I have disabled cors on strapi.

```js
 {
    name: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      enabled: false,
      origin: ['*'],
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
      headers: '*'
    },
  },
```

When I try to fetch data from `getStaticProps` I receive an error:

```
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 1337
  }
```

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/pages/2');
    const pages = await res.json();

    return {
      props: { title: pages.data.attributes.title },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return { props: { title: 'failed' } };
  }
}
```

The interesting part is that if I use the same fetching mechanism inside a hook it works:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   getStaticProps();
 }, []);
```

Does anybody have an ideea on why will this happen?

Comment: Idk, looks valid, try with axios, the cors also should not be a problem while you on local host or same domen

Comment: Isn’t you need to do getStaticPaths first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the request(fetch) url to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: It worked here (using Next13). Thanks! Any ideas why this error happen? I hope the production backend url works